# How to fit a boundary to a scatter plot

Tags: fitting

I am playing around with some diffusion simulations using random walks. For example, if I generate many random walks from the same parent distribution (a Gaussian) as:

```
 ManyRandomWalks = 
 Table[
       RandomWalkData = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
       RandomWalk = 1 +  Accumulate[RandomWalkData]; 

       RandomWalk,
       {i, 1, 200}
     ]
```

It will look like this:

[image]

One can bound this scatter with the equation:
$$f(t) =  A + \sqrt{D t} + B t$$
[image]

I'd like to make a fit of this to get a more accurate value of $D$ -- a diffusion constant -- so far the best method I can think of is to bin the data by index or $x$-axis and then perform a statistic or count on the bin and then fit this -- much in a similar how one would fit a histogram.

The other approach might me to do some MLE like `FindDistributionParameters` and define my function as a PDF, extracting parameter values that way.

Are there any inbuilt features to achieve what I want?

Comment: `StandardDeviation[ManyRandomWalks]` will give you the sqrt of variance at each of your 100 time steps. You could fit that curve and relate variance as a function of time to your diffusion coefficient. e.g. `Show[
 ListPlot[
  StandardDeviation[ManyRandomWalks]
  ],
 ListPlot[ManyRandomWalks],
 Plot[
  Evaluate[
   NonlinearModelFit[StandardDeviation[ManyRandomWalks], 
     Sqrt[a*t], {{a, 2}}, t]["BestFit"]]
  , {t, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red
  ]
 , PlotRange -> All
 ]`

Comment: I was thinking on a similar line of thought except with `2Sqrt[2] StandardDeviation[...]`

Comment: It depends on what you know about the data generation process and what you want the envelope to represent.  If you know all of the parameters of the data generation process AND you want the envelope to contain, say, 99% of all potential (not sample) values, then `Plot[{1 + 2.5758293035489004` Sqrt[x], 
   1 - 2.5758293035489004` Sqrt[x]}, {x, 1, 100}, PlotStyle -> Red]]` will do that.

Comment: If you don't know the parameters or the structure of the data generation process but you want the envelope to contain, say, the middle 99% of all sample values, then you could use `ListPlot[{Transpose[{Range[100], (Quantile[#, 0.995] &) /@ 
     Transpose[ManyRandomWalks]}],
  Transpose[{Range[100], (Quantile[#, 0.005] &) /@ 
     Transpose[ManyRandomWalks]}]}, Joined -> True]
`.

Comment: @JimB Well the point is more that I want to extract a diffusion parameter, $D$, but those are pretty useful commands to plot an envelope. I've added more to my equation in the main text

Comment: What heck is a diffusion constant?  It seems that you have made up a parameter/function (`f[t]`) that has no relation to the method generating the data. Note that by the very method of generating the data, there is a dependence induced that violates the assumption of independence associated with fitting a curve with `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Just doodling, running `mrwb = Transpose@({Max@#, Min@#} & /@ Transpose@ManyRandomWalks);` and then `ListPlot[mrwb, Joined -> True]` gives you the upper and lower bounds.

Comment: You'll still need to define what you want the envelope to represent.  For the example you give, you still need to specify the proportion of values to be found in the envelope.  If you need a general method where you only have data (and no specific data generation process), then that will also require a definition of what the envelope represents and you'll still likely need to specify a proportion of values to be found in the envelope.  If all points were independent, then @AntonAntonov 's Quantile regression functions might be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose one had a bunch of time series with no specifics about the data generation mechanism but did know that each time series was generated independently from the others.  (Yes, that's using a somewhat loose interpretation of independence.)

Further one wants to estimate an envelope that would contain the central $100(1-\alpha)$% of the observations for each time step such that the envelope has the following functional form:

$$f(t)=A\pm \sqrt{D t}+B t$$

One could find the sample estimates of the $1-\alpha/2$% and $\alpha/2$% quantiles for each time step and then fit a regression to get estimates of the parameters $A$, $B$, and $D$.

Using the OP's simulated data (`ManyRandomWalks`) we create a dataset that has the time step and a $-1$ associated with the lower quantiles and $+1$ associated with the upper quantiles and then run `NonlinearModelFit`.

```
α = 0.05;
lower = Quantile[#, α/2] & /@ Transpose[ManyRandomWalks];
upper = Quantile[#, 1 - α/2] & /@ Transpose[ManyRandomWalks];
data = Transpose[{Join[Range[n], Range[n]],
    Join[ConstantArray[-1, n], ConstantArray[1, n]],
    Join[lower, upper]}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, a + p Sqrt[d t] + b t, {a, b, d}, {t, p}];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 0.227842, b -> 0.0196022, d -> 4.00303} *)
```

Now plot everything:

```
Show[ListPlot[ManyRandomWalks, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thin],
 Plot[{a + Sqrt[d t] + b t, a - Sqrt[d t] + b t} /. nlm["BestFitParameters"], {t, 0, n}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], Red}}],
 ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 3}]], PlotStyle -> {{Black, PointSize[0.01]}}]]
```

[image: Time series, quantiles, and fit]

Comment: This is a really cool approach. This is what I was after! I have posted my own approach below where I use a multiple of the standard deviation to determine the boundary and then fit that.

Answer (score 4):

If the objective is to determine an envelope in the following form

$$f(t)=A\pm \sqrt{D t}+B t$$

that contains a desired expected proportion ($1-\alpha$) of the values at each time step, then for the time series mentioned the coefficients are $A=1$, $B=0$, and $D=(\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2))^2$ where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the standard normal cumulative distribution function.  No data is needed.

```
(* Generate several time series *)
nSim = 200
n = 100
ManyRandomWalks = Table[RandomWalkData = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n];
   RandomWalk = 1 + Accumulate[RandomWalkData];
   RandomWalk, {i, 1, nSim}];

(* Set parameters associated with this particular method of generating a time series *)
(* No need to estimate those from the data *)
α = 0.01;  (* Proportion of observations expected to be outside the envelope *)
{a, d, b} = {1, 
  InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - α/2]^2, 0}

(* Plot the time series and an envelope containing the central 100(1-α)% of the values
   for each time step *)
Show[ListPlot[ManyRandomWalks, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Thin],
 Plot[{a + Sqrt[d t] + b t, a - Sqrt[d t] + b t}, {t, 0, n}, PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.01], Red}}]]
```

[image: Multiple time series and envelope containing 99% of the distribution for each time step]

I've connected the points as a reminder that there are *not* 100*200 independent points for which to subject to a regression.

Answer (score 0):

I had a go at my own approach where I run multiple simulations of a random walk, all drawn from the same distribution. I join all the walks and sort them by $x$-index, and calculate the standard deviation and mean. Then taking $a \sigma \pm \mu$ defines the boundary of the data.

```
F[A_, B_, C_, D_, t_] := A + B t + C Sqrt[D t];

NSim = 512;
NInd = 128;
\[Sigma]SF = 2Sqrt[2];

\[Mu] = 1;
\[Sigma] = 1;

JoinedManyRandomWalk = 
    Apply[
            Join,
            Table[
                    RandomWalkData = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1], NInd];
                    RandomWalk = Transpose[{Range[NInd], Accumulate[RandomWalkData]}]; 
                    RandomWalk,
                    {i, 1, NSim}
                ]
            ];

            IndexList = DeleteDuplicates[JoinedManyRandomWalk[[1;;,1]]];

            StantisticsManyRandomWalk = 
            Table[
                    SortedByIndex = Select[JoinedManyRandomWalk, #[[1]] == IndexList[[i]] &];
                        \[Mu]SBI = Mean[SortedByIndex[[1;;,2]]];
                        \[Sigma]SBI = StandardDeviation[SortedByIndex[[1;;,2]]];

                    {Around[\[Mu]SBI, \[Sigma]SF \[Sigma]SBI], \[Mu]SBI + \[Sigma]SF \[Sigma]SBI, \[Mu]SBI - \[Sigma]SF \[Sigma]SBI, \[Mu]SBI},
                    {i, 1, Length[IndexList]}
                ];

                UpperFit = NonlinearModelFit[StantisticsManyRandomWalk[[1;;,2]], F[aa, bb, 1, dd, t], {aa, bb, dd}, t];
                LowerFit = NonlinearModelFit[StantisticsManyRandomWalk[[1;;,3]], F[aa, bb, -1, dd, t], {aa, bb, dd}, t];
                    UpperFitParams = {aa, bb, dd} /. UpperFit["BestFitParameters"];
                    LowerFitParams = {aa, bb, dd} /. LowerFit["BestFitParameters"];

                    UpperLowerFitsPlot = 
                    Show[
                            {
                                Plot[{UpperFit[x], LowerFit[x]},{x, 0, NInd}, PlotStyle->Directive[Red]],
                                ListPlot[JoinedManyRandomWalk]
                            }, 
                            PlotRange->All, Frame->True
                        ]
```

I haven't played around with JimB's answer just yet, but the above also works when one has non-zero means for the generating distribution.

[image]