# Find Equation for Line Bounding Bottom of Scatter Plot

Tags: fitting

I have a scatter plot and I am trying to get the equation of a line that best fits the bottom bound of the data.

I started by taking some guesses for the best form of the boundary equation and used the FindFit[] command to test out each. Once I found a good shape I used it to split the data and create a subset of the data that was closest to the bottom boundary. I then used the FindFit[] command again with the same form for the equation and got a line that more closely fit the bottom boundary.

When I took the sum of the squares error for this line with my data I got a number over 100 which isn't great. Is there a better way to do this? I tried to follow what I found in these posts [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/607510) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215638/how-to-fit-a-boundary-to-a-scatter-plot) and I was unsuccessful. Any suggestions are appreciated.

The code for my data to fit and resulting fit line are as follows.

```
datatofit = {{6.737172338, 3.363690623}, {7.050660212, 
3.373736489}, {7.045260043, 2.970956386}, {7.029287617, 
2.9525655}, {7.004950478, 2.879583858}, {6.974853608, 
2.86146603}, {6.941458132, 2.818494481}, {6.906952777, 
2.893338455}, {6.872201926, 2.940551101}, {6.837925451, 
3.397634859}, {6.803204973, 3.552844431}, {6.766544775, 
3.244249901}, {6.71850745, 3.302987412}, {6.684253549, 
3.167875865}, {6.66670728, 3.150775565}, {6.654886001, 
3.152303268}, {6.647275038, 3.151626188}, {6.643345749, 
3.151580709}, {6.64064312, 3.151574041}, {7.046091938, 
3.120075363}, {7.040626586, 2.771751037}, {7.024372252, 
2.799740928}, {6.999594641, 2.669548897}, {6.968712172, 
2.676528958}, {6.934228877, 2.624395294}, {6.898397676, 
2.652516685}, {6.861701263, 3.106205768}, {6.824856341, 
3.256504668}, {6.786708972, 3.083377532}, {6.744894076, 
3.219777785}, {6.68699347, 3.464187669}, {6.644085885, 
3.056803258}, {6.621036724, 3.03776599}, {6.60495429, 
3.03613608}, {6.593188858, 3.028994499}, {6.584495417, 
3.032142225}, {6.578697835, 3.032760756}, {7.043005505, 
2.879433241}, {7.037448284, 2.673586176}, {7.021021612, 
2.731079036}, {6.995891975, 2.566450694}, {6.964546514, 
2.600742648}, {6.92940586, 2.532713837}, {6.892545224, 
2.547549465}, {6.854596368, 2.771142903}, {6.816023846, 
3.123130369}, {6.775368031, 3.093750555}, {6.7299056, 
3.183432893}, {6.664947098, 3.667093691}, {6.615699834, 
2.983366728}, {6.588638333, 3.392473696}, {6.569315509, 
2.950492375}, {6.554261586, 2.941110252}, {6.542808184, 
2.941959397}, {6.533554849, 2.93893594}, {7.040691711, 
2.698683379}, {7.035116631, 2.621157784}, {7.018574159, 
2.700002587}, {6.993203755, 2.511981159}, {6.961459733, 
2.560957061}, {6.925824728, 2.487887417}, {6.888304185, 
2.509698731}, {6.849403353, 3.013369851}, {6.809502199, 
3.030071466}, {6.767022251, 3.453330064}, {6.718737756, 
3.093764566}, {6.648469337, 3.580313549}, {6.593848593, 
2.877026086}, {6.563586948, 3.152084598}, {6.541449976, 
2.830720899}, {6.524255063, 2.827916495}, {6.510411715, 
2.826588059}, {6.498860923, 2.824406461}, {7.038955285, 
2.578493867}, {7.033340199, 2.612255811}, {7.016687959, 
2.735690273}, {6.991143306, 2.508233093}, {6.959143325, 
2.555844374}, {6.923117192, 2.49172362}, {6.88506039, 
2.536450569}, {6.845406911, 3.071325015}, {6.804569678, 
3.193536334}, {6.760718398, 3.28270189}, {6.710350047, 
2.531280794}, {6.635755922, 3.20519061}, {6.57698951, 
2.26708585}, {6.543796226, 2.457274245}, {6.519703559, 
2.229251888}, {6.500484118, 2.68381051}, {6.484778548, 
2.226266777}, {6.471324049, 2.229252698}, {7.037601367, 
2.5107129}, {7.031963505, 2.564917697}, {7.015230995, 
2.700816343}, {6.989544414, 2.815891687}, {6.957335874, 
2.507864027}, {6.920995503, 2.851306634}, {6.882559183, 
2.500670143}, {6.842343633, 2.927637977}, {6.800739526, 
2.597890463}, {6.755802639, 3.059142293}, {6.703736537, 
2.526782669}, {6.625558242, 2.932715688}, {6.563584803, 
2.196284669}, {6.528268014, 2.276971557}, {6.502230053, 
2.142517738}, {6.481350429, 2.280845624}, {6.464057366, 
2.127040407}, {6.449274977, 3.210672349}, {7.036520362, 
2.48691801}, {7.030859594, 2.567515379}, {7.014069926, 
2.658174137}, {6.988285965, 2.773057218}, {6.955909261, 
2.509486114}, {6.919324165, 2.811164587}, {6.880558873, 
2.524767089}, {6.839891932, 2.917997801}, {6.797684653, 
2.617454777}, {6.751920865, 3.12821285}, {6.698498976, 
2.265103094}, {6.617668027, 2.851725101}, {6.552843345, 
1.914902384}, {6.515720946, 1.997611706}, {6.488148018, 
1.858929325}, {6.465919878, 1.961247735}, {6.447365016, 
1.841455432}, {6.431261185, 1.991596183}, {7.035653479, 
2.441673234}, {7.029979193, 2.642091664}, {7.013143124, 
2.779600057}, {6.987259413, 2.655408023}, {6.954754304, 
2.747056288}, {6.917982547, 2.690503028}, {6.878965321, 
2.671670335}, {6.837984295, 2.792041578}, {6.795288058, 
2.699023107}, {6.748789425, 2.994343796}, {6.69434619, 
2.75154734}, {6.611333377, 2.416987663}, {6.544183314, 
1.670533864}, {6.505492489, 1.745627845}, {6.4767104, 
1.592734733}, {6.453310046, 1.646655847}, {6.433635399, 
1.566881917}, {6.416503415, 1.6386405}, {7.034954678, 
2.430667632}, {7.029269788, 2.655392115}, {7.012381848, 
2.779696857}, {6.986424477, 2.677937026}, {6.953816738, 
2.767393148}, {6.916904312, 2.738390317}, {6.877678574, 
2.521709116}, {6.836410168, 2.903247296}, {6.793320608, 
2.691670804}, {6.746267116, 2.973871121}, {6.690902848, 
2.8373169}, {6.606132978, 2.004034878}, {6.537142696, 
1.358901692}, {6.497198187, 1.492049861}, {6.467300528, 
1.202542717}, {6.443067018, 1.278133712}, {6.422348331, 
1.139119465}, {6.404380246, 1.193699038}, {7.034360231, 
2.423314873}, {7.028676326, 2.546343642}, {7.011758013, 
2.70421933}, {6.985764669, 2.732327838}, {6.953065808, 
2.492944411}, {6.916027603, 2.828091797}, {6.87662091, 
2.502793251}, {6.835117845, 2.956424635}, {6.791725157, 
2.785362746}, {6.744227722, 2.725070054}, {6.688177644, 
2.952462805}, {6.601925407, 1.871037226}, {6.531483793, 
3.299572125}, {6.490419284, 1.205062821}, {6.459686231, 
0.924268761}, {6.43460432, 1.072051642}, {6.41317736, 
0.799702673}, {6.394433027, 0.874613658}, {7.033887306, 
2.414621979}, {7.028191073, 2.584108445}, {7.011251342, 
2.677415351}, {6.98520808, 2.591920501}, {6.952431456, 
2.728131626}, {6.915295189, 2.606394808}, {6.875752864, 
2.764029792}, {6.834058649, 2.629637742}, {6.790420478, 
3.07524121}, {6.742551507, 2.963775838}, {6.685933428, 
3.052845912}, {6.598483391, 1.771794681}, {6.526679942, 
3.711712717}, {6.484933022, 1.110138892}, {6.453429566, 
2.880676607}, {6.427598138, 0.827650948}, {6.405553788, 
0.631667532}, {6.386130329, 0.760793308}, {7.033485774, 
2.424465446}, {7.027784029, 2.542896896}, {7.010825267, 
2.676392444}, {6.984727707, 2.426663261}, {6.951895818, 
2.503322157}, {6.914674556, 2.668239461}, {6.87504636, 
2.71191227}, {6.833198996, 2.515308877}, {6.789335686, 
2.708438633}, {6.741153283, 2.490874554}, {6.684096853, 
3.032019326}, {6.59566427, 1.686277852}, {6.522838247, 
2.919478967}, {6.480288152, 0.986717582}, {6.448176753, 
2.068486954}, {6.421847708, 0.625051368}, {6.39926062, 
1.922526712}, {6.379303182, 0.356377592}, {7.033156909, 
2.411926653}, {7.027450152, 2.541483248}, {7.010464596, 
2.678526802}, {6.984341108, 2.740824687}, {6.951478592, 
2.794615538}, {6.914169479, 2.558769959}, {6.874430575, 
2.843349391}, {6.832468962, 2.465629313}, {6.788452692, 
2.980813388}, {6.740044845, 2.796268712}, {6.682518511, 
2.973088953}, {6.593055138, 1.602870812}, {6.519532175, 
2.67604757}, {6.476504456, 0.922451616}, {6.44392189, 
1.551595069}, {6.417042066, 0.524349666}, {6.394007742, 
1.335879104}, {6.373604641, 0.204979694}, {7.032874567, 
2.410828768}, {7.027159736, 2.607313012}, {7.010167791, 
2.626230999}, {6.984022698, 2.525194094}, {6.951121482, 
2.676686105}, {6.913762616, 2.432960144}, {6.873943192, 
2.602109532}, {6.831868118, 2.424174076}, {6.787698864, 
2.833240042}, {6.739079714, 2.429085504}, {6.681285512, 
3.080801999}, {6.516860422, 2.105024931}, {6.473298911, 
0.874160363}, {6.440230786, 1.285081302}, {6.413106094, 
0.456291156}, {6.389685571, 0.973943373}, {6.368894179, 
0.098754837}, {7.032645935, 2.405591528}, {7.026910561, 
2.372253613}, {7.009913701, 2.487133006}, {6.983737617, 
2.364848558}, {6.950791466, 2.524420007}, {6.91340328, 
2.364589563}, {6.873512579, 2.823145133}, {6.831364697, 
2.400296221}, {6.787055213, 2.679382786}, {6.738285943, 
2.409901849}, {6.68016282, 2.899877109}, {6.514641322, 
1.9369223}, {6.470610335, 0.836101475}, {6.437300126, 
1.129164882}, {6.409790246, 0.405443991}, {6.38602318, 
0.686981094}, {6.364910446, 0.028242141}, {7.032440554, 
2.405579999}, {7.026721599, 2.360197275}, {7.009694316, 
2.478204395}, {6.983510617, 2.348796858}, {6.950549463, 
2.522441741}, {6.913104044, 2.350943474}, {6.873169546, 
2.634773752}, {6.830937015, 2.392838217}, {6.786543993, 
2.839201002}, {6.737598664, 2.397235599}, {6.679324934, 
2.832339738}, {6.512784374, 1.713420067}, {6.468415156, 
0.803487782}, {6.43476251, 1.036945302}, {6.40702598, 
0.362975169}, {6.382961843, 
0.599796071}, {6.361672483, -0.033748511}, {7.032269629, 
2.404195798}, {7.026546953, 2.311238526}, {7.009518105, 
2.44643103}, {6.983325046, 2.315294417}, {6.950301954, 
2.511458327}, {6.912841213, 2.336852323}, {6.872860057, 
2.641195519}, {6.830569453, 2.385042086}, {6.786088247, 
2.688150649}, {6.737051299, 2.385137509}, {6.678553276, 
2.699520498}, {6.511231072, 1.604350357}, {6.466562622, 
0.77860391}, {6.432747844, 1.093028664}, {6.404695153, 
0.331838296}, {6.380443334, 
0.610163948}, {6.358866139, -0.073129957}, {7.021387848, 
3.541701984}, {7.017318549, 3.366268739}, {7.004005224, 
3.379362555}, {6.983608703, 3.310765727}, {6.957981545, 
3.372186381}, {6.9300328, 3.238677971}, {6.901310421, 
3.513454512}, {6.873579569, 3.38958335}, {6.84697077, 
3.448019292}, {6.822146907, 3.672250607}, {6.797997064, 
3.421691746}, {6.773159504, 3.408306056}, {6.755629533, 
3.409602569}, {6.746650751, 3.405713642}, {6.742636776, 
3.405360568}, {6.74038778, 3.405358496}, {6.738733887, 
3.405358717}, {6.737366301, 3.405358714}, {7.009119349, 
3.333399632}, {7.004912836, 2.99492421}, {6.990923136, 
2.974801307}, {6.969367763, 2.896208713}, {6.942122197, 
2.879163429}, {6.91185393, 2.820121984}, {6.880016883, 
2.965103286}, {6.848151481, 2.961425017}, {6.81626398, 
3.386735289}, {6.784651895, 3.441177003}, {6.751090931, 
3.280806418}, {6.712540883, 3.506529359}, {6.682764581, 
3.234167522}, {6.665778087, 3.219308724}, {6.654539923, 
3.220829707}, {6.647345542, 3.220185319}, {6.643545231, 
3.220137592}, {6.641009464, 3.220132845}, {7.00275519, 
3.104026368}, {6.998431434, 2.788884407}, {6.984162424, 
2.806069462}, {6.962097894, 2.686021977}, {6.93390774, 
2.681217719}, {6.902432022, 2.632561023}, {6.868884985, 
2.670789886}, {6.834996486, 3.073172065}, {6.800221064, 
3.278592264}, {6.764769929, 3.217612391}, {6.726026299, 
3.234278978}, {6.679223478, 3.566967796}, {6.642084036, 
3.132144621}, {6.620080487, 3.116832626}, {6.604457483, 
3.115273601}, {6.592882502, 3.108860221}, {6.584419577, 
3.111700897}, {6.578710123, 3.112401791}, {6.998453514, 
2.884078687}, {6.994040671, 2.676144008}, {6.979589633, 
2.722120393}, {6.957083533, 2.575196145}, {6.928331939, 
2.598627047}, {6.895995935, 2.541203344}, {6.861383373, 
2.557500226}, {6.826040369, 2.772999508}, {6.789260743, 
3.149417027}, {6.751169366, 3.225516519}, {6.708668456, 
3.19683746}, {6.655960276, 3.63032235}, {6.613106365, 
3.074207024}, {6.587176578, 3.395948961}, {6.568288904, 
3.045830522}, {6.553591418, 3.037174422}, {6.542342907, 
3.037655551}, {6.533478246, 3.034637296}, {6.995257836, 
2.710463265}, {6.990840026, 2.612485842}, {6.976156825, 
2.681489905}, {6.95344572, 2.513754005}, {6.924218623, 
2.557578841}, {6.891257737, 2.496164396}, {6.855802202, 
2.516896036}, {6.819340411, 3.03692985}, {6.781177105, 
3.053046016}, {6.741178178, 3.155774023}, {6.695804347, 
3.098114561}, {6.638516975, 3.342320661}, {6.590926409, 
2.992880091}, {6.561614268, 3.240979384}, {6.540231203, 
2.947801818}, {6.523550665, 2.945132883}, {6.509802935, 
2.943379145}, {6.498535038, 2.940797565}, {6.99284548, 
2.571171245}, {6.988381018, 2.538146306}, {6.973591929, 
2.708241023}, {6.950678304, 2.439909927}, {6.921097543, 
2.504480264}, {6.88768125, 2.876971639}, {6.851603753, 
2.472316264}, {6.814325066, 2.797995352}, {6.775012875, 
2.718968741}, {6.733477612, 2.880545781}, {6.685861511, 
2.172919922}, {6.624807712, 2.797501221}, {6.573655321, 
1.823490126}, {6.541745821, 2.163771856}, {6.518234088, 
1.74777426}, {6.499406713, 2.52076469}, {6.484056326, 
1.726976337}, {6.470895399, 1.71411499}, {6.990983255, 
2.492374661}, {6.986505805, 2.521507171}, {6.971605514, 
2.691000161}, {6.94848282, 2.423092642}, {6.918675658, 
2.483312647}, {6.884913274, 2.726465955}, {6.848353042, 
2.472908418}, {6.810431393, 2.730279131}, {6.770206766, 
2.592288305}, {6.727600214, 2.86105508}, {6.67812493, 
2.257416686}, {6.614139375, 2.606553397}, {6.559854955, 
1.926487703}, {6.525922737, 2.04205007}, {6.500692551, 
1.858306873}, {6.4801801, 2.052948153}, {6.463153087, 
1.836944653}, {6.448645105, 3.186252252}, {6.989486885, 
2.447788691}, {6.984961003, 2.51823223}, {6.970017249, 
2.621197985}, {6.946754224, 2.654136753}, {6.916724071, 
2.722538609}, {6.882707695, 2.660782622}, {6.845750492, 
2.486855827}, {6.807332509, 2.705607007}, {6.766441258, 
2.616313927}, {6.722798257, 2.789726234}, {6.671931189, 
2.266686188}, {6.605619456, 2.582709675}, {6.548886496, 
1.971415758}, {6.513142743, 2.042152732}, {6.486316292, 
1.908717509}, {6.464518697, 1.996837852}, {6.446212182, 
1.889947327}, {6.430375826, 2.015387471}, {6.988286989, 
2.442797784}, {6.983753986, 2.523709108}, {6.968764455, 
2.815435814}, {6.945394744, 2.696070989}, {6.915228657, 
2.571777841}, {6.880977312, 2.736142572}, {6.843719044, 
2.625985493}, {6.804812407, 2.846609949}, {6.763408347, 
2.702631955}, {6.719175614, 2.725144312}, {6.666998881, 
2.812838126}, {6.598727966, 2.217421041}, {6.539968152, 
1.68036073}, {6.502715394, 1.753586116}, {6.47470821, 
1.609945838}, {6.451696211, 1.661851878}, {6.432379608, 
1.585905749}, {6.415510904, 1.653235924}, {6.987325382, 
2.428485538}, {6.982762868, 2.520642611}, {6.967719299, 
2.812619236}, {6.944097527, 2.716088442}, {6.913954197, 
2.543537804}, {6.87951661, 2.782685466}, {6.842022117, 
2.524040008}, {6.802835042, 2.960676849}, {6.761005457, 
2.699207732}, {6.715960506, 2.649555904}, {6.663108202, 
2.937761994}, {6.593322988, 1.891491441}, {6.532799258, 
1.360130197}, {6.494335951, 1.493722149}, {6.4652259, 
1.215214833}, {6.441309979, 1.286996334}, {6.420946513, 
1.155820892}, {6.403239809, 1.20877977}, {6.986517798, 
2.418721529}, {6.981959967, 2.516103273}, {6.966871231, 
2.707231238}, {6.943365135, 2.418431508}, {6.912955104, 
2.481041434}, {6.878336136, 2.864718778}, {6.84063932, 
2.493227818}, {6.80119304, 3.043388324}, {6.758959301, 
2.777887654}, {6.713480217, 2.578313592}, {6.659925271, 
3.0554261}, {6.588805235, 1.767714977}, {6.526893155, 
3.45736794}, {6.48731299, 1.206367522}, {6.457408188, 
0.945768081}, {6.432749806, 1.0869155}, {6.411664902, 
0.833238974}, {6.393075558, 0.900365879}, {6.985868568, 
2.39792015}, {6.981309469, 2.448437951}, {6.966163453, 
2.532392349}, {6.942630126, 2.462298954}, {6.912118892, 
2.711297056}, {6.877386636, 2.492756468}, {6.839524414, 
2.779518238}, {6.799848732, 2.562641964}, {6.757354724, 
3.094399317}, {6.711435272, 2.62743483}, {6.657060781, 
3.174913746}, {6.585146237, 1.688094305}, {6.521969739, 
3.41364081}, {6.48164058, 1.13711006}, {6.450958698, 
2.846539242}, {6.425646606, 0.896185308}, {6.403861401, 
0.744364294}, {6.384737069, 0.845871862}, {6.985337571, 
2.399150046}, {6.980746124, 2.606605224}, {6.965589764, 
2.677156504}, {6.941988084, 2.639323645}, {6.911420561, 
2.724689307}, {6.876596508, 2.702502904}, {6.838626888, 
2.812464811}, {6.798769366, 2.632561509}, {6.755966001, 
2.737586457}, {6.70970576, 2.511833139}, {6.654946343, 
2.978520481}, {6.581822314, 1.600239559}, {6.517952253, 
2.712632523}, {6.476923884, 0.981958276}, {6.445659866, 
2.035336396}, {6.419767371, 0.643196925}, {6.397498621, 
1.944480114}, {6.377793288, 0.403246413}, {6.98488373, 
2.405672661}, {6.980285513, 2.506241622}, {6.965115695, 
2.68036809}, {6.941468071, 2.766335724}, {6.91082076, 
2.853747521}, {6.875961946, 2.567132928}, {6.837833066, 
2.885985043}, {6.797828896, 2.459373833}, {6.754837292, 
2.742977197}, {6.708347546, 2.42044813}, {6.653122793, 
2.906196311}, {6.579265379, 1.526810823}, {6.514604203, 
2.500879394}, {6.473015497, 0.905592505}, {6.441240019, 
1.525323353}, {6.414919186, 0.515710199}, {6.392173836, 
1.320588181}, {6.372018259, 0.205196385}, {6.984495737, 
2.401439557}, {6.979931063, 2.627776046}, {6.964701582, 
2.672227083}, {6.941031686, 2.539974864}, {6.910324882, 
2.717804569}, {6.875406259, 2.436626084}, {6.837170521, 
2.601983053}, {6.797076282, 2.411391368}, {6.753928413, 
2.862968749}, {6.707237176, 2.387636149}, {6.651656207, 
2.949589832}, {6.511835988, 1.988418613}, {6.469758781, 
0.855749384}, {6.437618252, 1.281756011}, {6.410839786, 
0.445009267}, {6.387699425, 0.953176956}, {6.36717515, 
0.094736261}, {6.984166098, 2.394056378}, {6.979581812, 
2.51976677}, {6.964358662, 2.578668676}, {6.940664454, 
2.50945657}, {6.909937511, 2.657961257}, {6.874914928, 
2.621988611}, {6.836650401, 2.630219135}, {6.796406011, 
2.617593723}, {6.753107947, 2.617818296}, {6.706181283, 
2.610073938}, {6.650287374, 2.776940244}, {6.509566677, 
1.856344851}, {6.467052204, 0.816069506}, {6.434436932, 
1.113129647}, {6.407397081, 0.389667533}, {6.383938828, 
0.675287851}, {6.36320708, 0.013796113}, {6.983901887, 
2.394277751}, {6.979300989, 2.350943153}, {6.964083028, 
2.442414337}, {6.940335188, 2.34079414}, {6.909601437, 
2.534763847}, {6.874551906, 2.341245184}, {6.836169757, 
2.65065494}, {6.795903763, 2.373474174}, {6.752482957, 
2.894138331}, {6.705386817, 2.323014233}, {6.649273702, 
2.888122523}, {6.507589265, 1.655459882}, {6.464839239, 
0.784409443}, {6.431964994, 1.021987115}, {6.404557351, 
0.349725216}, {6.380898844, 
0.585498495}, {6.359823197, -0.042474931}, {6.983659377, 
2.392955434}, {6.97906581, 2.301237496}, {6.963837288, 
2.396246737}, {6.94008025, 2.306048454}, {6.909340835, 
2.524239683}, {6.874201695, 2.325594093}, {6.8358115, 
2.656288849}, {6.795409868, 2.364834796}, {6.751950885, 
2.692288624}, {6.704754512, 2.300977942}, {6.648361564, 
2.635953782}, {6.505973336, 1.572561081}, {6.462881392, 
0.758794965}, {6.429805958, 1.083726553}, {6.402195244, 
0.3172726}, {6.378271874, 
0.591334001}, {6.356973385, -0.084955223}, {6.992214922, 
3.176493752}, {6.988810316, 3.282279458}, {6.977223644, 
3.329380539}, {6.959304463, 3.228229582}, {6.936189756, 
3.344283466}, {6.911058348, 3.203824492}, {6.885410299, 
3.440714169}, {6.859699948, 3.404569564}, {6.835646283, 
3.394310454}, {6.813240258, 3.673407136}, {6.791815033, 
3.375189449}, {6.770521883, 3.36525816}, {6.755107451, 
3.366630444}, {6.746585121, 3.363286485}, {6.742720128, 
3.362921189}, {6.740516803, 3.362920996}, {6.73891736, 
3.362921781}, {6.73764641, 3.362921834}, {6.976464727, 
3.354189316}, {6.972851195, 2.955448686}, {6.960584373, 
2.944559515}, {6.941451688, 2.856659177}, {6.916453466, 
2.872523801}, {6.888799322, 2.83725635}, {6.859788043, 
3.462034734}, {6.829831408, 3.067748609}, {6.800294453, 
3.291632175}, {6.771101337, 3.457157338}, {6.740897032, 
3.213113902}, {6.707725781, 3.515985268}, {6.681497064, 
3.173971992}, {6.665355376, 3.160608058}, {6.65468603, 
3.162314592}, {6.647604098, 3.161899782}, {6.643547369, 
3.161854192}, {6.640893501, 3.161851331}, {6.968326079, 
3.092400997}, {6.964612152, 2.758367581}, {6.952001524, 
2.779234508}, {6.9322402, 2.664730667}, {6.906213587, 
2.671555346}, {6.877184042, 2.65580265}, {6.846503142, 
2.693272953}, {6.814180361, 3.12673241}, {6.781763158, 
3.277419627}, {6.748761911, 3.325077833}, {6.713427999, 
3.165498903}, {6.672982025, 3.617645559}, {6.640172368, 
3.073737955}, {6.61895858, 3.060384346}, {6.603999622, 
3.059159648}, {6.592635503, 3.052986431}, {6.584381499, 
3.056034427}, {6.578769034, 3.056624963}, {6.962765024, 
2.859040582}, {6.958993815, 2.645943758}, {6.946128126, 
2.686453784}, {6.925882664, 2.564846554}, {6.899303274, 
2.59155271}, {6.869369267, 2.575220391}, {6.837434536, 
2.598298152}, {6.803458093, 3.159433557}, {6.769012522, 
3.133085967}, {6.733400968, 3.207552825}, {6.694528099, 
3.167679581}, {6.648736976, 3.639779884}, {6.610545781, 
3.012325574}, {6.585669918, 3.369481906}, {6.567311158, 
2.987407431}, {6.553357577, 2.979041898}, {6.541958516, 
2.98001569}, {6.533118606, 2.977127321}, {6.958681796, 
2.685039585}, {6.954859829, 2.58113644}, {6.941793162, 
2.641290454}, {6.92124671, 2.510725273}, {6.894135677, 
2.56837116}, {6.86351419, 2.539615257}, {6.830740051, 
2.57673396}, {6.79550934, 3.018180298}, {6.759495118, 
3.029310982}, {6.721877721, 3.130597252}, {6.680281944, 
3.066498713}, {6.630124678, 3.306008097}, {6.587790205, 
2.903931905}, {6.559954274, 3.178817182}, {6.53923098, 
2.866788717}, {6.522652585, 2.865335777}, {6.509287055, 
2.864630931}, {6.498349444, 2.862792046}, {6.955585336, 
2.593915033}, {6.95174978, 2.582057423}, {6.93853889, 
2.730687172}, {6.917790428, 2.520559153}, {6.890254007, 
2.56596699}, {6.859138592, 2.988364424}, {6.825643863, 
2.599462725}, {6.789483734, 3.079088874}, {6.752400691, 
2.752097758}, {6.713179097, 3.32088671}, {6.669315007, 
2.443270308}, {6.615825438, 2.806002432}, {6.570298127, 
2.294253166}, {6.539806323, 2.443447679}, {6.516895962, 
2.266062601}, {6.498533237, 2.690492488}, {6.483227365, 
2.265815138}, {6.470474898, 2.269815209}, {6.953178801, 
2.498106873}, {6.949285214, 2.516910941}, {6.93598529, 
2.683738574}, {6.915053741, 2.858631419}, {6.887239263, 
2.509337756}, {6.855741275, 2.903255918}, {6.821623854, 
2.552429882}, {6.784845617, 3.003888991}, {6.746764429, 
2.685175038}, {6.706291623, 3.179205594}, {6.660628221, 
2.327311259}, {6.60472103, 2.590040214}, {6.556327746, 
2.104446758}, {6.523727251, 2.189169716}, {6.499091783, 
2.057764678}, {6.47911554, 2.19327725}, {6.462279634, 
2.043622143}, {6.447935747, 3.213002481}, {6.951259341, 
2.481056969}, {6.947350991, 2.516970762}, {6.933950342, 
2.608136516}, {6.912852778, 2.817791209}, {6.884822947, 
2.515328488}, {6.853015076, 2.860983232}, {6.818524707, 
2.56694289}, {6.781112069, 2.967621489}, {6.742290315, 
2.726788293}, {6.700939985, 2.6594261}, {6.653852707, 
2.12231287}, {6.595713829, 2.443114105}, {6.544929444, 
1.870272903}, {6.510609749, 1.950211337}, {6.484530162, 
1.816173267}, {6.463227703, 1.910042526}, {6.445058198, 
1.798471589}, {6.429532184, 1.936866545}, {6.949732547, 
2.425818733}, {6.945798062, 2.647872884}, {6.932376272, 
2.813944879}, {6.911149817, 2.661534012}, {6.882908577, 
2.762892226}, {6.850826742, 2.69687097}, {6.816023411, 
2.671563593}, {6.778192368, 2.790164386}, {6.738669474, 
2.761900904}, {6.696527895, 2.559816741}, {6.648353304, 
2.878873278}, {6.588525125, 2.154850826}, {6.535861648, 
1.629850271}, {6.500140174, 1.707699189}, {6.472835011, 
1.556257492}, {6.450336086, 1.610651685}, {6.43113596, 
1.530743306}, {6.414550213, 1.598507617}, {6.948483336, 
2.41512146}, {6.944577711, 2.672779495}, {6.931058541, 
2.807931751}, {6.909720324, 2.696789596}, {6.881332699, 
2.772042308}, {6.849049771, 2.759730298}, {6.813964267, 
2.607154141}, {6.775752408, 2.91460007}, {6.735821461, 
2.776517102}, {6.693007547, 2.474779395}, {6.643919249, 
3.061882146}, {6.582312632, 1.828557981}, {6.52842868, 
1.318150806}, {6.491511525, 1.46145624}, {6.46309646, 
1.168606532}, {6.439606376, 1.243184131}, {6.41968226, 
1.105699476}, {6.402124113, 1.161187379}, {6.947464035, 
2.407289049}, {6.943514178, 2.484775976}, {6.929981953, 
2.685880014}, {6.908572716, 2.767078431}, {6.880065636, 
2.844733616}, {6.847637996, 2.866394864}, {6.812345227, 
2.558133726}, {6.77383994, 2.964282557}, {6.733409678, 
2.852804017}, {6.690050977, 2.401487661}, {6.640309135, 
3.177482755}, {6.577518339, 1.706039542}, {6.522368289, 
3.513245993}, {6.484454258, 1.166829801}, {6.455123055, 
0.894187456}, {6.430959859, 1.048593245}, {6.410139145, 
0.771835548}, {6.391867922, 0.842580556}, {6.946644327, 
2.394509865}, {6.942665889, 2.597720865}, {6.929076585, 
2.643707164}, {6.907644583, 2.591481111}, {6.879023116, 
2.793249539}, {6.846438269, 2.575657911}, {6.810953093, 
2.819561121}, {6.772199415, 2.558582859}, {6.731529537, 
2.813200376}, {6.687766819, 2.528568343}, {6.637297718, 
3.257931369}, {6.573540851, 1.622223537}, {6.517353699, 
3.275267407}, {6.478605976, 1.070037293}, {6.448562749, 
2.799185077}, {6.423782982, 0.794084741}, {6.402317371, 
0.599477411}, {6.383344134, 0.734462636}, {6.945928126, 
2.405343228}, {6.941975511, 2.47826747}, {6.928360481, 
2.665457982}, {6.906830577, 2.803411106}, {6.878134187, 
2.774331285}, {6.845468321, 2.617861868}, {6.809857123, 
2.686404041}, {6.770833356, 2.478964041}, {6.730039181, 
2.725768607}, {6.685847795, 2.305261446}, {6.634854335, 
2.923746224}, {6.570388073, 1.546405144}, {6.513219843, 
2.61325003}, {6.473760638, 0.948137439}, {6.443185493, 
1.995912996}, {6.417729533, 0.596728631}, {6.395706918, 
1.976153715}, {6.376280034, 0.334535519}, {6.94534765, 
2.392308781}, {6.941393529, 2.477487831}, {6.927735761, 
2.671098121}, {6.906201481, 2.669899429}, {6.877462342, 
2.836139305}, {6.844631395, 2.511605154}, {6.808860414, 
2.835869359}, {6.769732478, 2.419971558}, {6.728702049, 
2.710203756}, {6.684097748, 2.260339238}, {6.632641469, 
2.838537027}, {6.567704107, 1.476304786}, {6.509759459, 
2.39030416}, {6.469765684, 0.882194919}, {6.438657748, 
1.494315494}, {6.412729015, 0.492519209}, {6.390337529, 
1.30024496}, {6.370388325, 0.177167498}, {6.9448677, 
2.388479281}, {6.940905607, 2.530093893}, {6.927250447, 
2.554735541}, {6.905617196, 2.467264542}, {6.876843774, 
2.679963867}, {6.843960337, 2.393308753}, {6.808117903, 
2.574092056}, {6.768842931, 2.371032047}, {6.727473167, 
2.838215747}, {6.682770336, 2.223367174}, {6.631018912, 
2.835450039}, {6.565479648, 1.419552194}, {6.506871279, 
1.926955165}, {6.46635346, 0.833560503}, {6.434938146, 
1.283391272}, {6.4086394, 0.423734393}, {6.385775385, 
0.925330872}, {6.365540926, 0.069801878}, {6.944457784, 
2.383420748}, {6.940474486, 2.336793071}, {6.926811707, 
2.420448091}, {6.905164352, 2.330982551}, {6.876319134, 
2.526546277}, {6.843440116, 2.326598993}, {6.807441403, 
2.89697162}, {6.768073313, 2.342206415}, {6.726614565, 
2.62499806}, {6.681711802, 2.188854817}, {6.629657497, 
2.681773662}, {6.504470027, 1.806784862}, {6.463621864, 
0.794606643}, {6.431730104, 1.09406179}, {6.405195745, 
0.370542987}, {6.381998443, 
0.659540632}, {6.361366672, -0.006277668}, {6.944114718, 
2.383243601}, {6.940127989, 2.318491247}, {6.926429223, 
2.408388294}, {6.904803241, 2.31285621}, {6.875861967, 
2.524762582}, {6.842892749, 2.312357128}, {6.806905814, 
2.639766472}, {6.767447262, 2.332406084}, {6.72580953, 
2.850519321}, {6.680802637, 2.158377068}};

bottomfitline = Table[{x, 10.6008*Sin[x] + 16.2661*Cos[x] - 16.9753 - .08}, {x, 6.3,
 7, .1}];
ListPlot[{datatofit, bottomfitline}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 10] &) /@ {"x", "y"}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try constructing a fit manually by producing your own cost function. Here I use the square difference residuals if the points error to the upside of the curve, just like least squares. But if the points fall below it I make the costs harsher by using an exponentially rising cost and penalty multiplier. Here $\varepsilon$ is the absolute residual, the $x_i,y_i$ are the points, $p$ is the penalty and $f$ is the model to fit.

$$
\varepsilon=\left|y_i-f(x_i)\right|\\\text{cost}(x_i,y_i|f)=
\begin{cases}
 \varepsilon^2 & y_i\geq f(x_i) \\
 \exp(p \varepsilon) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

We then minimize the total costs. A higher penalty leads to a flatter line which is less tolerant of any points falling below the curve, while a lower penalty creates a more curvy line that allows a few points to fall below:

```
residual[f_, data_, penalty_] := Sum[
  With[{fy = f[p[[1]]], y = p[[2]], x = p[[1]]},
   Piecewise[{{(fy - y)^2, y >= fy}}, Exp[penalty*(fy - y)]]
   ],
  {p, data}, Method -> "Procedural"]

f[x_] := a*Sin[x] + b*Cos[x] - c

{err, sol} = NMinimize[residual[f, datatofit, 15.], {a, b, c}, 
   Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"];

fittedmodel = f[x] /. sol

Show[
 ListPlot[datatofit, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 10] &) /@ {"x", "y"}],
 Plot[fittedmodel, {x, Min[datatofit[[All, 1]]], 
   Max[datatofit[[All, 1]]]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much this was very helpful

Comment: I'm now trying to change this to an upper bound. It isn't working well currently. Do you have any suggestions? I've modified the code by changing the residual function to this: residual[f_, data_, penalty_] := 
 Sum[With[{fy = f[p[[1]]], y = p[[2]], x = p[[1]]}, 
   Piecewise[{{(y - fy)^2, y <= fy}}, Exp[penalty*(y - fy)]]], {p, 
   data}, Method -> "Procedural"]

Comment: @mathemagician617 in what way is it not working well? I took your changes and they produce an upper bound which is mostly okay on the right but too conservative on the initial left slope. If the fit is the problem, you should probably look for a better model for the upper bound, and your data are [heteroskedastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity) which is a common cause of problems in regressions.

Comment: @flinty Where did you find `Method -> "Procedural"` ?

Comment: @flinty thank you

Answer (score 4):

Because you have no theoretical model to represent the "bottom bound of the data", that feature is in the eye of the beholder.  It seems that there are two tasks:  (1) Find a set of data points that represent the bottom bound of the data, and (2) Attempt to find a curve that adequately describes that set of bounding data.

While you could just draw in a bottom bound that satisfies the definition in your mind, the excellent link you gave (https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/607510 with answer by Marco Theil can get you task 1.

```
(* Interpolate the raw data so that you have an approximation of that data on a fine and regular grid *)
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
t = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 6.35, 7.05, 0.0001}];

(* Estimate the "bottom" of the curve based on the excellent post you mentioned *)
σ0 = 50;  (* You need to decide on this value *)
base = EstimatedBackground[TimeSeries[t], σ0, Method -> {"SNIP", 0}];
ListLinePlot[{data, base}]
```

[image: raw data and estimate of bottom bound of data]

Now you need to determine a curve form that adequately describes the bottom bound.  Two linear segments with sines and cosines seems promising.

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: If your objective was more about finding smoother boundary (like what @flinty did) but you wanted the boundary where say only 5% of the points would be below (as opposed to 0% as stated in your question, then you might consider quantile regression.

Comment: @JimBanks for the suggestion!